# STL Map: What does this command mean?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, insertion

I've come across a solution of a competition problem that uses the STL Map, with a different kind of insertion that I've already known. I know these kind of insertions (and their differences):

`Map[key] = value;` and `Map.insert(make_pair(key,val));`

But this one I've no idea what it's doing, just that it works for the problem that I need to solve:

```
   std::map<int, int> freq;
   int inp;
   // ...

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &inp);
        freq [inp]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &inp);
        freq [inp]--;
    }
```

Where freq is a map with a pair of ints, and inp is a normal integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you show where you initialized freq?, if freq is a "pair" of ints you need to access them  with "freq[inp].first" and "freq[inp].second" and as far as i know "pair" don't have the + or - operator overloaded.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf ("%d", &inp);
    freq [inp]++;
}
```

here, freq is storing how many times an integer was found on the input, if the input is: 0, 0, 0, 1,1

map[0] = 3, and map[1] = 2

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    scanf ("%d", &inp);
    freq [inp]--;
}
```

the same, just subtracting.

in this case, you can't:

```
Map.insert(make_pair(key,val));
```

becouse with:

```
std::map<int, int> freq;
```

you're saying that your map will have an integer as a "key" and an intenger as a "value", is no't a "map of pairs" is just a map, would have been a map of pairs if you had initialized as
    std::map > freq;

```
Map[Key] = Value;
```

if this is a competition problem, i recommend you to just use an array, set it size to the biggest you will need, and initialize it in 0 as required.

Answer (score 4):

When you use the lookup operator `[]` and the key isn't already in the map, an entry is created using a value initialized value of the type. In this case a value initialized `int` is zero initialized, giving an initial value of 0. The `++` or `--` then operates on that value.

Answer (score 2):

> I know these kind of insertions (and their differences):
>
> ```
> Map[key] = value;
> ```

`Map[key]` is not strictly for insertions.  You can assign to that value as well.  The postincr/postdecr operators do modify those values, as a side effect.

So `Map[key]++` is legal, and does what you might expect -- increments the value stored at `Map[key]`.  Equivalent to:

```
Map[key] = Map[key] + 1
```